# VB Net + Mysql + System.NullReferenceException

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I have an error with System.NullReferenceException mysql select "COMMAND.CommandText = "select * from Users where user= @user and pass= @pass"" at click button.

```
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Mydb.My.MySettings.Mydb").ToString)
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    MysqlConn.Open()
    COMMAND.CommandText = "select * from Users where user= @user and pass= @pass"
    COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox_Username.Text), DBNull.Value, TextBox_Username.Text))
    COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox_Password.Text), DBNull.Value, TextBox_Password.Text))
    COMMAND = New MySqlCommand(COMMAND.CommandText, MysqlConn)
    READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
```

What is wrong ?

Edit :

This is the complete code button:

```
MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Mydb.My.MySettings.Mydb").ConnectionString)
    Dim READER As MySqlDataReader
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.WaitCursor
    MysqlConn.Open()
    COMMAND.CommandText = "select * from Users where user= @user and pass= @pass"
    COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox_Username.Text), DBNull.Value, TextBox_Username.Text))
    COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox_Password.Text), DBNull.Value, TextBox_Password.Text))
    READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
    Dim count As Integer
    count = 0
        While READER.Read
            count = count + 1
        End While
        If count = 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Usuario y Contraseña Correctos")
            Dim role As String = READER("tipo")
            If role = "Administrador" Then
                Inicio.Show()
            ElseIf role = "Calidad" Then
                Calidad.Show()
            ElseIf role = "Almacen" Then
                Almacen.Show()
            ElseIf role = "Oficina" Then
                Oficina.Show()
            ElseIf role = "Minas" Then
                Minas.Show()
            End If
            Me.Hide()
        ElseIf count > 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Usuario y Contraseña Duplicados")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Usuario y Contraseña Incorrectos")
        End If
        MysqlConn.Close()

    MysqlConn.Open()
    COMMAND.CommandText = "insert into Registro_Login (user,fecha,ip) values (@user,@fecha,@ip)"
    COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(TextBox_Username.Text), DBNull.Value, TextBox_Username.Text))
    COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fecha", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Label4.Text), DBNull.Value, Label4.Text))
    COMMAND.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ip", If(String.IsNullOrEmpty(Label3.Text), DBNull.Value, Label3.Text))
    READER = COMMAND.ExecuteReader
    MysqlConn.Close()
    Me.Cursor = Cursors.Default
```

But the same problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

COMMAND seems be not defined before it is being used. Like you have defined READER, define COMMAND as well then use it.And also change below code:

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Mydb.My.MySettings.Mydb")
```

To

```
ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings("Mydb.My.MySettings.Mydb").ConnectionString
```

And .ToString should .ToString() as it is a method.

I am not sure if you are really able to compile this code or post the entire code, required to suggest solution, if you have not done it.

Comment: Where are you defining COMMAND object?

Comment: in Public Class Form 
Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
Dim COMMAND As MySqlCommand
Dim READER As MySqlDataReader

Comment: Highly suspect that your COMMAND object is null - not been initialized, please debug and check that

Comment: Ok solve.... I have change with Dim COMMAND As New MySqlCommand And Dim MysqlConn As New MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.

Comment: Cool. Please mark it as answer if my solution was helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Your Command has no connection set.

replace this:

```
 COMMAND.CommandText = "select * from Users where user= @user and pass= @pass"
```

with

```
 COMMAND = New MySqlCommand("select * from Users where user= @user and pass= @pass", MysqlConn)
```